# @FormParam doesn't work with 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

The client side will send the request in json format. However, it looks like the value can't be got by `@FormParam` annotation. I tried to change the `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` but it didn't work.

Which kind of change shall I make on JAVA side to receive the data correctly?

For example, JSON data is

```
var postData = {
  'uipath': 'xxx\abc\location1',
  'value': 'Hello World!'
};
```

The JAX-RS method is

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/receive")
public Object getValueFromUIPath(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
            @FormParam("uipath") String uiPath,
            @FormParam("value") String value) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you try `@Consumes("application/json")` ? and see if this works

Comment: json should always be in double quotes.

Comment: I also tried "application/json" but it didn't work with @FormParam annotation.

Comment: JS side have changed the header as `"'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"`, and send the data with `req.write(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(postData)));`

JAVA side uses `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`

But the FormParam is still null.

Answer (score 0):

for your information

1. use consumes annotaion
2. json should be double quoted

and coming to the answer , you are creating json object

```
{
  'uipath': 'xxx\abc\location1',
  'value': 'Hello World!'
}
```

however you are suppose to consume two string fields, not an object. you have two options, whether consume object have two fields `uipath` and `value`, or send simple value rather then json object.